# Is it possible to put a Webview in a Homescreen Widget?

Tags: android

I want to create a homescreen widget app with a webview inside it that loads a website. is it possible? if so, is there a tutorial or example I can look at? I cant find anything

**edit**

Apparently WebView is not supported. My question now is, is there a workaround this restriction? any ideas welcome

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible?

`WebView` is not a supported `View` [for use with an app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

Comment: Is there a way around it?

Comment: @codefish578841441: You can download the Android source code, modify it to allow `WebView` in an app widget, compile the resulting OS, pour that into a ROM mod, install that ROM mod on your device, and then create an app widget for your device that uses a `WebView`. Or, you can write your own home screen and offer your own extended API for app widgets that allows for `WebView` widgets to be used.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. The only problem is that I like the ROM I have installed now and I don't want to replace it.